# Add custom attribute directive to each ngx-datatable row

Tags: html, angular, ngx-datatable

I have a table created with ngx-datatable that requires a tooltip on each row.
I also have a custom attribute directive that creates tooltips on hover and I'm trying to use the same code.

How can I add the attribute directive to each ngx-datatable row so the tooltip works?

Comment: Any solution you got?